# Why is my question downvoted?

Tags: support

I would appreciate assistance to make [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1578861/what-is-the-latest-rdp-protocol-version-supported-by-remmina) acceptable to this site, but it has been downvoted twice and my comment asking for guidance was deleted.  I have tried to add some background that makes it clear how a power user would find the question acceptable.

I also note [32 questions about Remmina](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remmina) which makes my question on topic.  If I should ask this question in another site, would someone provides me some guidance?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The Windows Server 2012 reference is to show what research I have done, and to show concern that a minimum RDP protocol level is needed to connect to Windows 10.  I edited the question again to clarify.  I hope that someone familiar with Remmina/FreeRDP can provide a fact-based reference to the highest protocol level it supports in their latest version of the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posting an actual answer to this:

I my humble opinion, it makes utterly no sense why [this question was downvoted](https://superuser.com/q/1578861/167207) so quickly out of the gate by multiple people. Checking the documentation for [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) — which is what Remmina uses for RDP connections — I see no clear compatibility version statement.

So what I decided to do is upvote the question, edit it a bit for clarity — even though it was fairly clear beforehand — and then donate 50+ bounty to get some attention for the question.

The end result is — as of this post — the question has been upvoted into the positive territory and three answers were posted; each providing some nice and substantial details.

Sometimes these sites seem frustrating when downvotes happen, but I am personally proud to say that I showed how being fair — and donating rep for a bounty — to draw attention really recovered this question. Not only does the original poster now have an answer, but — given the vagueness of the core RDP version question — this is an authoritative source for info on RDP version compatibility.

Comment: Most of the votes was due to the original revision.  Only after the downvotes was the question improved

Comment: Those dozens of questions, arguably deserved downvotes, for the same reason as the original revision of the author’s question.  It seems the question received downvotes, and it was improved, and now received upvotes.